# Libgdx reset checked state of a button programatically

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have two buttons (A & B) and I'm trying to have my code such that when I click on button A then click on B, A resets itself back to normal state(released). Each of the buttons has 3 states: up, down and checked.

```
if (one_h.isPressed()) {
      //reset button 2 if pressed
                two_h.getStyle().up = menuSkin10.getDrawable("200 released");
                two_h.getStyle().down = menuSkin10.getDrawable("200 pressed");
                two_h.getStyle().checked = menuSkin10.getDrawable("200 gray");


            } else if (two_h.isPressed()) {
                //reset button 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it ! Buttons in libgdx have a toggle() state. Thus in my case...

```
if (buttonA.isPressed()) {

 if (buttonB.isChecked()) 
  {
      buttonB.toggle(); //reset to normal state
  }
}
```